# Query an articles table and get result only if the value of another table is X

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of "articles" with a unique ID, a TABLE value and a text field:

> *ARTICLES*
>
> ## ID | TABLE | TEXT
>
> 019281  | food | fresh food blah
>
> 92811 | food | canned food blah
>
> 21192 | cloth | wool cloth blah
>
> 4392 | cloth | light cloth blah

then I have the tables:

> *FOOD*
>
> ## ID | STORAGE | VALUEX | VALUEY
>
> 019281  | B1 | 1 | 9
>
> 92811 | B2 | 4 | 4
>
> 21192 | C1 | 8 | 1

&

> *CLOTH*
>
> ## ID | STORAGE | VALUEX | VALUEY
>
> 21192 | C1 | 8 | 1
>
> 4392 | C1 | 2 | 3

I have tried with INNER JOIN but it is killing my mysql. And maybe it is wrong, I am noobish.

`SELECT *
FROM food, cloth
LEFT OUTER JOIN articles
ON articles.text LIKE "%QUERY%"`

Right now I made a script that search ARTICLES for TEXT and if it is LIKE %QUERY%, a foreach loops where table = articles.table.
**I would like to filter out from selecting items with a low valuex or to create a new virtual table of items from every single table with an articles.text match, so sort it by valuex**.

Comment: You are right about my programming education, but I am an amateur programmer. I just asked for help on something I cannot fix by myself searching online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM articles a
LEFT OUTER JOIN food f on f.id = a.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN cloth c c.id = a.id 
where articles.text LIKE "%QUERY%" and f.valuex > 1 and c.valuex > 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot use this because of "and f.valuex > 1 and c.valuex > 1". It requires both f and c valuex > 1

Comment: i dont know what you want. i just put that there, i gave you a little push , do you want me to do your job?

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks anyway. You helped me. :)